# Disable automatic capitalization for a specific part in the document

Tags: ms-word

Is there a possibility to disable automatic capitalization for a specific part in the Word document?

Because in that part I give attribute names and I don't want them to capitalize because the system that I'm working with is case-sensitive.

Comment: No, Word provides no way to determine when or where automatic capitalization occurs. It's either on, or off. It might be possible using VBA code, with an event (WindowSelectionChange). Are you looking for a progammed solution?

Comment: No actually not thanks anyway